# Can I determine if the current function has been invoked via command substitution?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, subshell

```bsh
foo() {
  if [[ something ]]; then
    echo "The foo function was called directly."
  else
    echo "The foo function was invoked via command substitution."
  fi
}
```

Call foo directly:

`foo`

> The foo function was called directly.

Call foo via command substitution:

```bsh
a=$(foo) || exit 1
echo "${a}"
```

> The foo function was invoked via command substitution

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that one test that you could use is

```
if [[ $BASHPID -eq $$ ]]; then
    echo was called directly
else
    echo was called in a subshell
fi
```

The special value `$$` will be the process ID of the shell executing the script. This would not change in subshells (of which a command substitution is one).

The special value `$BASHPID` will be the process ID of the shell executing the current code.  This value *would* change inside a subshell.

Therefore, if they are different, the function is called in a subshell. You can't, as far as I know, know if this subshell is a command substitution or some other subshell.

You could also use

```
if [[ $BASH_SUBSHELL -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo was called directly
else
    echo was called in a subshell
fi
```

for the same effect in the code shown.

The `BASH_SUBSHELL` variable is incremented from zero for each additional level of nested subshells.

Comment: You could have answered my original question with a simple "No," and you would have been technically correct. Instead, you answered the question I should have asked in the first place. You, sir, are a rock star. Thank you very much.